# Getting same instance with filter and filter_by using different ID strings

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

*query 1*

```
style_id = u'373401'
self.session.query(ChromeYearMakeModelStyle).\
    filter_by(chromestyle_id=style_id).one()
```

`ChromeYearMakeModelStyle(373401)`

*query 2*

```
style_id = u'373401abc'
self.session.query(ChromeYearMakeModelStyle).\
    filter_by(chromestyle_id=style_id).one()
```

`ChromeYearMakeModelStyle(373401)`

*query 3*

```
style_id = u'373401def'
self.session.query(ChromeYearMakeModelStyle).\
    filter_by(chromestyle_id=style_id).one()
```

`ChromeYearMakeModelStyle(373401)`

Why am I getting the same output for all three queries?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. It's a case of GIGO. You are clearly using mysql as your database and you clearly have the `style_id` column defined as int. As far as mysql automatic type conversion is concerned the following are all equal

```
373401
373401abc
373401def
```

They all represent the same number 373401. So the result is correct.

Other databases such as postgresql have more strict type checking. For example the second value would produce something like `syntax error at abc`

Comment: I am using `Oracle` as a backend database.

Comment: ["SQL and PL/SQL are very “datatype friendly.” They attempt—whenever possible—to do what you ask them to do. Compare a number with a string, and SQL and PL/SQL will do that by converting the string to a number implicitly—behind the scenes—and then comparing them."](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-sep/o54asktom-2279184.html) This is btw. very unfriendly in my opinion...

Comment: Thanks for the link @IljaEverilä

Comment: I just find out that, It was happening due to `Unicode`. When I pass a string as `style_id` it is giving a proper error.